# How to append content of one file to another in Linux continuesly?

Tags: linux

I have a log file `log.log` that is created by the application, I want to have any new line added to this file continuously being added to another log file `historical_log.log`. How can I do that? I am using RHL7 at the moment.

Thank you

Comment: If you have your app sent long to STDOUT you can try something like:
`application|tee -a historical_log.log >log.log`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately, I do not have access to the app code so I cannot modify how the log.log file is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do what you want, I think:

```
tail -F log.log >>historical_log.log &
```

It's quick and dirty, but might be enough on it's own, or wrapped in a script.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful, I think this process needs to be running as when I am closing the terminal it stops doing the job. So far I ended up running a cron to append the lines.